# Recomposition of all items on using List<Interface> with LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

On using a `List<Interface>` with the LazyColumn recomposes all the items, instead if I use `List<Implementation>` it skips the recompositions intelligently.

For instance, if I use example 1 `MutableList` in composable recompostition happens for all items on addition operation to list, but in example 2 it skips intelligently. **WHY?**

Example 1:

```
    val selectionState: MutableList<ViewItemScratch> = remember {
      mutableStateListOf()
    }
```

Example 2:

```
    val selectionState: MutableList<TitleViewItemScratch> = remember {
      mutableStateListOf()
    }
```

Interface:

```kotlin
interface ViewItemScratch {
  val identifier: Int
  val layoutId: Int

  @SuppressLint("NotConstructor")
  @Composable
  fun ViewItem(
    lazyItemScope: LazyItemScope? = null,
    rowScope: RowScope? = null,
    columnScope: ColumnScope? = null
  ) {
  }
}
```

Implementation Class:

```kotlin
data class TitleViewItemScratch(
  val index: Int,
  val text: StringResolver,
  val modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  override val identifier: Int = text.hashCode()
) : ViewItemScratch {
  override val layoutId: Int
    get() = R.id.compose_view_title_view_item

  @Composable
  override fun ViewItem(
    lazyItemScope: LazyItemScope?, rowScope: RowScope?, columnScope: ColumnScope?
  ) {
    Text(
      modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
      text = text.resolve(),
    )
  }
}
```

Composable:

```kotlin
 @Composable
  private fun WithViewItemScratch() {
    val selectionState: MutableList<ViewItemScratch> = remember {
      mutableStateListOf()
    }
    val onButtonClick = remember {
      {
        selectionState.add(
          TitleViewItemScratch(
            index = selectionState.size + 1,
            text = UIString("Hello world #${selectionState.size + 1}"),
            identifier = selectionState.size + 1,
          )
        )
      }
    }
    Column {
      Button(onClick = {
        onButtonClick.invoke()
      }) {
        Text(text = "Add")
      }
      LazyColumn {
        items(
          items = selectionState,
          key = { viewItem: ViewItemScratch -> viewItem.identifier }
        ) { item ->
          item.ViewItem()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Compiler report(s):

```
restartable skippable fun ViewItem(
  unused stable lazyItemScope: LazyItemScope? = @static null
  unused stable rowScope: RowScope? = @static null
  unused stable columnScope: ColumnScope? = @static null
  unused <this>: ViewItemScratch
)
```

```
stable class TitleViewItemScratch {
  stable val index: Int
  stable val text: StringResolver
  stable val color: CompassColor
  stable val typography: CompassTypography
  stable val modifier: Modifier
  stable val identifier: Int
  <runtime stability> = Stable
}
```

Layout Inspector recompositions:

With List of Interface:
[image]

With List of Implementation/Concrete class:

[image]

Comment: on stabilizing the  ViewItemScratch Interface using `@Stable` annotation it skips the recompositions, but why? this interface is prolly considered stable as all the params type are stable

Comment: Another thing I found,

If the interface contains only one variable it is considered stable, otherwise it's considered unstable. I validated it through the layout inspector recompositions

Comment: is `Interface` in a module without Compose compiler executed on it?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes, it's in the same module. In fact it's all in the same file

Comment: IDK what i did differently this time, but its working LazyColumn skipping intelligently with List<Interface> as well - https://gist.github.com/hellosagar/6b5b5a309faf74d050ea8436991bcddc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting the Jetpack compose compiler report/metrics shows that the interface's stability is missing. Because the interface doesn't have logic but tells about the abstraction it brings. So if the interface doesn't explicitly promise the compose stability by applying `@Stable` or `@Immutable`, it's treated as unstable only.

The implementation is considered stable by default because it's a data class (which comes with `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation) with all properties as `val` (immutable).

Comment: I believe this is true, but I didn't find similar in their documentation about interfaces.
To back up this statement is it also written somewhere in their official documentation?

Comment: It's not written precisely in the context of Interfaces. But about reports, they have detailed doc about what exactly report terminologies means: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/compiler/design/compiler-metrics.md